# Setting a texture's "Max Size" while ensuring that its dimensions are still multiples of 4

Tags: unity

A version of my game has several large textures with dimensions that are multiples of 4 so that Crunch compression can kick in.

A ported version of my game, for platforms that have very limited RAM restrictions, will need us to limit the "Max Size" of our textures to 512 or 256, etc.

There are some cases in which a Crunch-friendly texture, when resized by Unity's "Max Size" parameter, will actually end up with dimensions that aren't multiples of 4.

`944x800` would end up as `512x434`, if we select "512", which isn't good for Crunch.

The naive solution in my mind is to write a simple script/tool that resizes/pads all my textures by a couple of pixels in such a way that Unity's resize will end up in a Crunch friendly way. However, I'd rather do that as a last recourse if possible.

Is there a more standard way to approach this situation of mine?

Comment: I'm surprised your images aren't power of two sizes in the first place. Are these sprites that are not being combined into an atlas?

Comment: @DMGregory yes that's right, because more often than not a couple will be enough to fill a 4096x4096 atlas and since the specific sprites that will be needed at any moment are hard to predict you're almost always guaranteed to load just as many atlases anyway. At the end being granular was more useful (for the original version of the game).